# Monospace font not displaying correctly on server

Tags: css, asp.net, font-family

I am trying to display a set of alphanumeric characters, one per line, and wanted to have them line up properly, so I used monospace font. It works fine when I try it locally (run from within Visual Studio, for example) but when I deploy the application it doesn't work. I am hoping it is not some browser setting because I cannot ask user to modify their browser settings.

This is the CSS:

```
.monoSpace {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

textarea using this style:

```
<textarea id="taLabelIDs" name="taLabelIDs" class="monoSpace w-100" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
```

This is what it looks like run locally:

[image: Local version]

This is what it looks like on server:

[image: On server]

Comment: @Azu Thank you. Can you change your comment to answer and I will mark it. This fixed my issue. Also, does this mean I can use any other font in place of 'Courier'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have given only monospace and not a certain font name, most probably your machine and the server use different default monospace fonts. Try to use for example font-family: 'Courier', monospace; to see if three is still any difference.

You could use any other monospace font, just first check the web-safe monospace fonts on the net.